# Page Up Button with Endless Scrolling

Tags: html

Does anyone have a code for a page up button with endless scrolling? So no matter where the visitor is on the page, they will always see the button to bring them back to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
<div id="toTop" style="position: fixed; right: 20px; bottom: 20px;" onclick="javascript: scroll(0, 0);">Top</div>
```

You can fancy it up with more CSS and a smooth JavaScript scroll behavior if you want, but this should at least get you started.